# How to initialize cppwinrt TimeSpan struct?

Tags: c++-winrt

According to the master docs for cppwinrt, Migrating C++..., "The equivalent C++/WinRT source code to set the value for a Windows Runtime property calls a method with the same name as the Windows Runtime property and a parameter for the new value:

```
record.UserState(newValue); // Set the UserState property
```

But this doesn't seem to work when attempting to set the TimeSpan property of a Duration object:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan(6000000);
Duration duration = Duration();
duration.TimeSpan(ts);
```

The third line produces an intellisense error on "duration": "Call of an object of class type without appropriate operator or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type." The build error for the same line is "Term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments." I should add that the constructor for Duration seems to have one argument, a TimeSpan, but that is not accepted either. How can one set the TimeSpan property of a Duration when using cppwinrt?

Answer (score 6):

Remember, in C++/WinRT `Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan` is simply a typedef of [std::chrono::duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), so you can use std::chrono's useful functionality.

Direct init:

`Duration duration{ std::chrono::milliseconds{ 100 }, DurationType::Automatic };`

Setting individually:

`Duration duration{ };
duration.TimeSpan = std::chrono::milliseconds{ 100 };`

Comment: Eh, what's up the negative rating for that, without even leaving a comment as to why?

Comment: It doesn't compile

Comment: If you forget the "using namespace" statements that were assumed in the original, you're going to have a hard time. But this certainly does compile: https://godbolt.org/z/vrYs43sza

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I can answer my own question. While it's called a "property" of Duration in the MSDN .NET docs, in this cppwinrt environment TimeSpan is not a property of Duration but rather is a data value of the Duration struct. So you don't set it using the above-described method for setting properties; you set it this way:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan(6000000);
Duration duration = Duration();
duration.TimeSpan = ts;
```

Hope that will help anyone else in a similar situation...

Answer (score 0):

`Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan` is defined

```cpp
using TimeSpan = std::chrono::duration<int64_t, impl::filetime_period>;
```

so when you have a function taking a `TimeSpan`, say `DispatcherQueueTimer::Interval`, you can simply do

```cpp
timer.Interval(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
```

or

```cpp
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals; timer.Interval(1s);
```